# search database to identify addresess

Tags: custom-search

we have about 1400 people in our database. All have email addresses and some have physical addresses. How can I sort/search so I can produce a list of those who have physical addresses? Once we have this list, is there a way to export that list to create mailing labels? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to this stack community. There are multiple ways you could get what you want.
I would use the Search Builder functionality. You can find it in the main menu Search-> Search Builder.

[image: search builder]

You can search the contacts where the address fields (such as city, street adress, or other address fields) are not empty.

You can then select actions (what to do with the list). You can export it and deal with it externally or you can select Mailing Labels - print to directly create mailing labels. You would probably want to configure Label format before doing so. You can do that by going to the Administer->Communication->Label Formats in the main menu.